# Install grub on ext2

Tags: partition, grub2, boot-loader, root-filesystem, ext2

Is it possible to install (and use) grub on the same ext2 partition as the linux root directory?
(Should you want to discuss 'why': to try, to understand and master.)

Comment: I have a system that does ... so ... I guess the answer is "yes, it is possible" - except I use EXT4 ... does that make my statement irrelevant?

Comment: I suppose not.  Seems to me that if ext4 works, ext2 will too.
Did you use regular grub2, or some alternate release?

Comment: regular grub2 installed as part of debian install

Comment: Have you legacy boot enabled?  I can get it to work with bios, but not with efi.

Comment: I always boot EFI

Comment: Have you done some specific configuration during or after install?  According to the specs (and fora) efi only supports fat.  Does 'dmesg | grep "EFI v"' return an efi version?

Comment: Oh, EFI, no that is on a FAT partition - I thought you were talking about grub

Comment: The initial question is about grub indeed, my wrong.  My real/next question is if I can set all up on a usb flash drive with one single ext2 partition.  Looks like that's possible, but only with bios.  No efi workaround?

Comment: EFI needs to be on a FAT32 partition I beleive